# Polymer update datalist

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0, html-datalist

I'm making a polymer element with some requirements. I've a list (ul) and two input fields. I need that one of the inputs update my list (there's no problem here). The other input should be able to define some default values for the first input, here I'm using a datalist.

I wrapped all in a polymer element. That's when I started having problems. I'm trying to  update the datalist inside the polymer element, the datalist is updated but the input doesn't show the new hints.

Also, I've noticed that if I have more than one of these elements all the input binds with the datalist of the first element. I don't understand this behaviour. Each element must bind to the list inside her scope.

One more thing that I need to figure out is how can I delete some of default values added.

Here is my code:

```
    <dom-module id="test-input" attributes="edit list type">

    <template>
        <!-- Here I have the first input that creates a list and I need to be binded with a datalist-->

        <div id="container">
            <div id="display" on-click="_openEdit">
                <div id="textDescription" class="textDescription">{{description}}</div>
                <ul id="list" class="list"></ul>

                <form id="addContainer" class="addContainer" action="#" method="post">
                    <label for="newitem">{{label}}</label>
                    <!--<input type="text" name="newitem" id="newitem" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" required>-->

                    <input list="defaultValues" name="newitem" id="newitem" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" required>
                    <!-- I've added this options so we can see that it's working but when the datalist is updated it doesn't show-->
                    <datalist id="defaultValues">
                        <option value="option added on html"></option>
                        <option value="option added on html 2"></option>

                    </datalist>
                    <input type="submit" id="addToList" value={{buttonText}}>
                </form>


            </div>

            <!-- Here I have the second input that updates the datalist default values-->

            <div id="edit">
                <div id="extendedList">
                    <div>Enter the default values</div>

                    <form id="extendedAddContainer" class="addContainer" action="#" method="post">
                        <label for="extendedNewitem">{{label}}</label>
                        <input type="text" name="extendedNewitem" id="extendedNewitem"
                               placeholder="enter default values" required>
                        <input type="submit" id="extendedAddToList" value={{buttonText}}>
                    </form>

                </div>


            </div>
        </div>


    </template>


    <script>
        defaultValueCounter = 0;

        function isEmpty(str) {
            return !str.replace(/^\s+/g, '').length; // boolean (`true` if field is empty)
        }


        Polymer({
            is: "test-input",
            properties: {
                buttonText: {
                    type: String,
                    value: "Add"
                }
            },
            ready: function () {
                /* Start: add input to list */
                var list = this.$.list,
                        field = this.$.newitem,
                        form = this.$.addContainer;

                form.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
                    if (field.validity.valid && !isEmpty(field.value)) {
                        list.innerHTML += '<li class="style-scope list-input">' + field.value + '</li>';
                        field.value = '';
                        field.focus();
                        ev.preventDefault();
                    }

                }, false);

                list.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
                    var t = ev.target;
                    if (t.tagName === 'LI') {
                        t.parentNode.removeChild(t);

                    }

                    ev.preventDefault();
                }, false);

                /* End: add input to list */

                /* Start: Add default values */
                var extendedList = this.$.defaultValues,
                        extendedField = this.$.extendedNewitem,
                        extendedForm = this.$.extendedAddContainer,
                        container = this.$.extendedList,
                        defaultList = this.$.defaultList;


                extendedForm.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
/* Here I add things to the datalist */
                    if (extendedField.validity.valid && !isEmpty(extendedField.value)) {
                        aux = document.createElement("option");
                        aux.value = extendedField.value;
                        extendedList.appendChild(aux);
                        extendedField.value = '';
                        extendedField.focus();
                    }

                }, false);


            }
            /* End: Add default values */

        });


    </script>

</dom-module>
```

Thanks in advance!